No me sale para heredar windows forms

la verdad nose porque no me sale, busque pero no encuentro nada. Muchas gracias¡¡

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

hola amigo, podrías ser un poco mas claro de que es lo que deseas obtener para poder ayudarte, en especial, a que te refieres con "heredar windows form", no es muy claro si quieres hacer un proyecto o te deberia de salir otro tipo de proyecto que no vez.
